# Testing a method that reads from standard input and outputs to standard output

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a method which reads lines from the standard input and writes lines to the standard output.

From within a JUnit test, how can I send input to the method, and how can I capture its output so that I can make assertions on it?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/212360/31260

Answer (score 18):

You should not have a method which reads from standard input and writes to standard output.

You should have a method which accepts as parameters the `InputStream` from which it reads, and the `PrintStream` into which it writes. (This is an application, at the method level, of a principle known as [Dependency Injection (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which is generally used at the class level.)

Then, under normal circumstances, you invoke that method passing it `System.in` and `System.out` as parameters.

But when you want to test it, you can pass it an `InputStream` and a `PrintStream` that you have created for test purposes.

So, you can use something along these lines:

```
void testMyAwesomeMethod( String testInput, String expectedOutput )
{
    byte[] bytes = testInput.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( bytes );
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    try( PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( stringWriter ) )
    {
        myAwesomeMethod( inputStream, printWriter );
    }
    String result = stringWriter.toString();
    assert result.equals( expectedOutput );
}
```